# mingw32-make can not be found in environment variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, xgboost, ming

I want to use install xgboost on my windows 7. but before that, when i installed MinGW-W64, it needed to use make command and when i type `which mingw32-make` in my git bash, it said that there is no `mingw32-make` in my Path ( although i gave an address for the directory of `mingw32-make` in the Path environment variable). So could someone help me with this or at least propose an easy way to use xgboost within ipython notebook?

[image]

Comment: `PATH` is for folders names - not for full path with program name at the end. You need path without `mingw32-make`  in `PATH`

Comment: @saeid-hedayati: In the future, try to copy-paste text of output/code that you want to add to your question.  Doing so makes it easier to search for your question/answer it than just having a screenshot.

Comment: @Grisha Levit thanks . duly noted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PATH` is for folders names in which command `which` is searching for program name `mingw32-make` and in which system is searching for program when you run it. But you put folder name with program name at the end.

You need rather `C:/ ... /mingw64/bin` without `mingw32-make` at the end.